# How to import the cordova plugins in my project

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, vuejs2

I have created a Vuejs project along with cordova for Hybrid APP.

In one of the file I want to use Cordova plugin so for that I had added the plugin through

`cordova add plugin` command and it got installed and I can see the plugin in the `plugins` folder of the root directory.

Now how should I use this plugin in my code ?

Anyone used cordova plugins with vue ?

**update**

```
console.log(cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner);

Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
```

Comment: any found resources about this question?

Answer (score -1):

the cordova plugin will be the window object and you can use any where in the javascript code

Comment: tried doing console.log() and the plugin name it say doesnot exist

Comment: try `cordova.plugins.plugin_name`

Answer (score -2):

So let's suppose you just added the plugin "plugin" with :

```
cordova add plugin
```

Now you have your html page with cordova. And you link a javascript page in the body of this html page, like.
Then, in your javascript page, you can use the plugin you just added by doing something like : 
      cordova.plugins.plugin.functionWanted()

Comment: actually its the problem with Cordova Plugin barcodeScanner if you have cordova project tryinstalling it hat , and you will see it doesnot comes in the plugin list

Comment: Did you check if the name of your plugin is in the config.xml file of your project ?

Comment: absolutely its there and when I do , `cordova plugins` command in the CLI it is showing as well, its just that its not available in the window object

Comment: I never had this problem so I couldn't know what to do then, sorry :/. Hope you'll have an answer to this problem :)

Comment: I am building Hybrid App for the first time so kind of stuck with these plugins :(, Do you recommend any other Barcode Reader for Cordova

Comment: I have never used a barcode reader yet. So I couldn't recommend one in particular :/ . (I would try this one though : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-barcodescanner   or this one : http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/barcodeScanner/ ) ...  But your error message "Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined"  lets us think it might more be a cordova problem, maybe not with the plugin ?  Honestly, I wouldn't know sorry :/